# how to display the json data in extjs grid which is encoded in symfony controller

Tags: symfony, extjs4.2

hi please help with this iam trying to display a Extjs 4.2 grid panel with symfony 2 as backend.

my config.yml

grid:

```
pattern:   /grid
defaults:  { _controller:ExtAssExampleBundle:displaygrid:display}
requirements: { _format: (json), _method: GET }
```

my controller

class displaygridController extends Controller

{

```
public function displayAction()
{
      $repository = $em->getRepository('ExtAssexampdbBundle:movies');
$items = $repository->show();
    $response = json_encode($items);
   return $this->render('ExtAssExampleBundle:Default:grid.html.php',array('response'=>$response));
}
```

}

grid.html.php

Ext.onReady(function()

{ 
   Ext.define('movie', {

```
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields: [
                    {name:'id', type: 'int'},

                    {name:'title',type: 'string'}, 

                    {name:'director',type: 'string'},

                    {name:'released',type: 'string'},

                    {name:'genre', type: 'int'},

                    {name:'tagline',type:'string'}

                ] } );

var mystore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', 
{

    model: 'movie',
    autoSync: true,
    autoLoad: true,
    data:response,
    proxy: {
            type:'ajax',
            url:' ',
```

//what i need to pass over here

```
            reader: {

                    type:'json',
                    root: 'movies'

                    },
             writer:{
                    encode: true,
                        writeAllFields: true,
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                }
            },
});//store completed
   var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', 
{

    style: 'margin-top: 1%; margin-left: 24%',
    store: mystore,
    id:'grid',
    width: 700,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Movie Details',
    collapsible: true,
    closable:true,
    maximizable: true,
    frame:true,
    dirty:false,
    draggable: true,
    stripedRows: true,
    columns:
               [
        {header: 'MovieName', width: 100, sortable: true, dataIndex:response[0].title,editor:{xtype:  'textfield',allowBlank:false} },
        {header: 'Director Name', width: 100, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'director',editor: 'textfield',allowBlank:false},
{header: 'Released Date', width: 150, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'released',editor: 'datefield',renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d')},
```

{header:'Genre', width:150, sortable:true, dataIndex:'genre',editor:'numberfield',},
            {header: 'Tagline', width: 200, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'tagline',editor: 'textfield'},
        ],

```
});
            mystore.load(); 
            grid.render('table')
```

});

problem is how can i access the $response which has been sent by the symfony2 controller and display the values in the Extjs 4.2 grid.please help with this

Comment: please fix the code in your question :) any particular reason you set up the controller-route twice with different urls - once using annotation, once using yml configuration?

Comment: please check it now nifr i have edited my code

Comment: i tried those annotion because whether i can pass those annotation value is given in url of extjs but it dooesnot work so i removed it please help with this

Answer (score 0):

use the another controller to send the json data to grid like

class dispjsonController extends Controller

{

public function sendjsonAction()
    {

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('ExtAssexampdbBundle:movies');
$items = $repository->show();
$serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
$response = new Response($serializer->serialize($items, 'json')); 
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response; 
}
```

}

in routing set the route for the dispjsoncontroller

and now in view in the url give as:/app_dev.php/sendjson